# How can I access properties of another function in same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to put `NumberFormat` inside `OutlinedInput`. Also, i want to have different properties `format` for `NumberFormat`. (There will be a select window, which defines which of `format` properties to use.

I have this:

```
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";

import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

function NumberFormatCustom(props) {

  const { value, format, ...other} = props;

  return(
    <NumberFormat 
    {...other}
    format={format}
    mask="_"
    />
  )
}


export default function TextMaskPhone(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { value, name, label, onChange } = props;

  

  const [format, setFormat] = useState("+1 (###) ###-####");

  return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={doTest}>change</Button>
        <FormControl className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">{label}</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            className={classes.inputPhone}
            labelWidth="50"
            value={value}
            name={name}
            onChange={onChange}
            id="formatted-text-mask-input"
            inputComponent={NumberFormatCustom}
          />
        </FormControl>  
      </div>
  );
}
```

Help please, how can i pass `format`value from `TextMaskPhone` function into `NumberFormatCustom`?

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing what `OutlinedInput` is. Is it from a third-party library?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add it. Its from Material-UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use inputProps:

```
<OutlinedInput
      labelWidth="50"
      value={value}
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      inputProps={{
        format
      }}
      id="formatted-text-mask-input"
      inputComponent={NumberFormatCustom}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

since `inputComponent` take a component then simple do the below

```js
  <OutlinedInput
            className={classes.inputPhone}
            labelWidth="50"
            value={value}
            name={name}
            onChange={onChange}
            id="formatted-text-mask-input"
            inputComponent={()=> (<NumberFormatCustom format={format} />)}
          />
```

Comment: it works, but inputComponent loses all styling properties from OutlinedComponent :(